# Multi-node Elastic search cluster load balancer returns differently ranked results every time

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

We have a ES cluster on aws, where we have two nodes, each node having one shard with identical index in it.
We have documents that are returned in the sorted order first by score then by date.

Right now the scores returned are all equal, and dates are equal.

When we run same query, the order of documents differs between requests.

Is there any way to make the order consistent?

Comment: If the scores are equal and dates are equal then that makes sense because in theory they are all in equal order. You would have to add another sort like alphabetical by some third property to make the order consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When all other sort keys are equal, elasticsearch sorts documents by so-called [index order](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-sort.html#search-request-sort) (`_doc`) which is the order the documents appear in the index. This order can be different between primary and replica shards. In order to improve consistency of result for your users, you can add an additional sort key that would be unique for each record, for example `_uid` field.

Alternatively, you can tie each user to a particular shard if it's available by using your user session id or their username as a [preference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-preference.html). This way, while different users might still see different results, each user will consistently see the same order as long as the shard they were attached to is alive.